# Attempting to access message content without GatewayIntent

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want that whenever I write a message that says hello, the bot responses with a message in the console, but it's just giving me an error:

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] WARN JDA - Attempting to access message content without GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT.
Discord now requires to explicitly enable access to this using the MESSAGE_CONTENT intent.
Useful resources to learn more:
    - https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ
    - https://jda.wiki/using-jda/gateway-intents-and-member-cache-policy/
    - https://jda.wiki/using-jda/troubleshooting/#im-getting-closecode4014-disallowed-intents
Or suppress this warning if this is intentional with Message.suppressContentIntentWarning()
```

I tried using the links, but it didn't work.

```
public class NachrichtenReaktion extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onMessageReceived (MessageReceivedEvent ereignis)
    {

        if(ereignis.isFromGuild())
        {

            if(ereignis.getMessage().getContentStripped().equals("hallo")) {
                
                System.out.println("ufhsdijhsdifhdshfuihduisfh");
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to carefully study [ask]

Comment: @HoRn the question is fine, OP is getting a warning when using getContentStripped(). This is an absolutely acceptable question.

Answer (score 4):

You have to explicitly enable the MESSAGE_CONTENT intent. This is explained in the link from the warning: https://jda.wiki/using-jda/gateway-intents-and-member-cache-policy/

When building your JDA instance with a `JDABuilder`, you have to use `enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT)`. See the [docs](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#enableIntents(net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent,net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent...)).

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: you just need to allow your bot to do it in the dev portal.
[image]