# e.getMessage().getContentDisplay() returns empty String

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm learning jda and I coded my discord bot so that console send the message that I sent, but after executing this code, I send a random message in my test discord server, the console just prints nothing. Is anything wrong with my code? I also tried e.getMessage().getContentRaw(), but it returns same result.

Main Class

```
package net.lib.first;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message;
import net.lib.first.event.Listener;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        String token = (my bot token);
        JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(token);
        builder.addEventListeners(new Listener());
        builder.setActivity(Activity.playing("Type !ping"));
        builder.build();

        Message.suppressContentIntentWarning();
    }
}
```

Listener Class

```
package net.lib.first.event;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class Listener extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().getContentDisplay());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempting to access message content without GatewayIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73079928/attempting-to-access-message-content-without-gatewayintent)

Comment: Yes! Although I solved the problem now, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, I didn't add the method enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT) to builder.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but there is no option to enable GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT

only:

```
[...]
builder.createDefault("xxx")
                        .setActivity(Activity.playing("!help") )
                        .setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE)
                        .addEventListeners(new CommandListener() )
                        .addEventListeners(new VoiceListener() )
                        .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES)
                        .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGES)
                        .build();
[...]
```

I have enabled the above ones.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle checkbox "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" in your application to the ON position.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jeix.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** places where you need to enable the `message content` intent.

1. In the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

In your application, under **Bot** scroll down to **Privileged Gateway Intents**, and tick **Message Content Intent**

2. When creating the `JDA` instance

```java
JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT)
            .build();
```

After this, your messages should register.