# Java Discord Bot event.getMessage().getContentRaw() is empty

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am following a guide on how to create a discord bot in Java, but no matter what I do, the bot cannot take messages from server. It knows that they have been sent, but cannot get their content.

I've tried getContentRaw(), getcontentDisplayed(), getContentStripped() methods, but none of them return anything but an empty string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
            .setActivity(Activity.playing("something"))
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES)
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGES)
            .addEventListeners(new DiscordBot())
            .build();
}


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event.getMessage().getContentRaw());
    System.out.println(event.getAuthor().getName());

}
```

I can see the author in the console.

I also tried with different versions of the dependency, but what I've tried return same empty string.
I gave the bot administrator permissions (I don't wish to publish it, I am just creating it for fun), but it still doesn't work.

I tried to use enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT) method in the builder, but the program immediately stops with error code 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempting to access message content without GatewayIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73079928/attempting-to-access-message-content-without-gatewayintent)

Comment: after introducing .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS), program just ends with error code 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not add this: `GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT`
[enter image description here][1]
Discord if I'm not wrong recently added that without this option does not leave the message so, if you try tageando the bot will be shown, yesterday I spent the same thing but researching found the solution

(1) make sure to activate the corresponding inits in the discord developers portal
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VMRv.png

(2) add this to your code
[2]:

```
 JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
            .setActivity(Activity.playing("something"))
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT)
            .addEventListeners(new DiscordBot())
            .build();
```

- I also attach a video for your better understanding ->
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKxQ8uM8lhI&t=276s

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this was really bugging me lmao

Comment: Use comments field to thank the people who responded.